# Are there any US politicians that want to reduce housing prices?

Tags: united-states, economy, policy, federal-reserve, housing

Over the last year, the Federal Reserve has propping up the already historically high housing market [by purchasing/backing](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2020-09-01/fed-s-mortgage-buying-spree-at-1-trillion-with-no-end-in-sight) trillions of dollars of mortgages, preventing a decline in house prices like in 2008.

This seems to be a largely bipartisan thing, with lots of support (even if only implicitly).

I'm not so much interested in debating the merits themselves, but rather understanding the political alignment.

Are there any U.S. politicians that vocally advocate for housing market costs going down instead of keeping them where they currently are?

Comment: Related reading: [Rent Is Too Damn High Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rent_Is_Too_Damn_High_Party)

Comment: It's an iffy issue because that's where most (average) people's net worth is. See this q for instance:  https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/49655/did-the-wealth-gap-shrink-under-trump-pre-pandemic Note that according to JP Morgan the 2006 peak has been exceeded already https://www.jpmorgan.com/insights/research/us-housing-risk

Comment: See also https://blogs.lse.ac.uk/politicsandpolicy/the-housing-conundrum/ (That's written from the UK perspective, but the same conundrum applies elsewhere.)

Comment: @Fizz, certainly. There's an inherent conflict between buyers and sellers. The most common position favors sellers (and I can see why); I'm still curious if there's anyone who advocates for low housing prices favoring buyers. (EDIT: Thanks for link.)

Comment: US politicians are the political arms of the corporate class.  It's equivalent to asking the fox, who rules over the chicken coop, to work against the interests of the housing industry/Wall Street.

Comment: A socialist or communist party would advocate for public housing, like that in Cuba.

Answer (score 4):

For reasons explained in [this blog](https://blogs.lse.ac.uk/politicsandpolicy/the-housing-conundrum/) you'd expect
at best politicians aligned with renters and/or the
youngest generations to say such things and even then
they have to take into account the superior voting power
of older generations who mostly own property. There seems to be a (historical, at least) [correlation](https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-32065625) between politicians' positions on such matters and the percentage of people who own houses.

Consequently, the measures proposed will usually not say explicitly
they want to drive down property values, but instead propose
rent controls etc. In the US, politicians from the leftist
wing of the Democratic party have made such proposals, e.g.
Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez and Bernie Sanders have
[made](https://www.thenation.com/article/archive/aoc-sanders-housing-rent/) such rent-control proposals at a national level.

On the other hand, studies on the effects of de-control [have shown](https://www.brookings.edu/research/what-does-economic-evidence-tell-us-about-the-effects-of-rent-contro)
a greater increase in property values in de-controlled areas. So
it is implicit that price controls will at least limit the rise in
value of property prices.

In general, it seems based on [surveys](https://www.cato.org/blog/poll-59-americans-favor-building-more-housing-their-neighborhood) that both Republicans and Democrats would favor an increase in housing supply (and depending how much that supply increase is, it could limit or even drive down prices). But when it comes to specifics, e.g. building duplexes in the suburbs, such measures have been [defeated](https://www.virginiamercury.com/2020/01/23/house-panel-rejects-plan-to-boost-affordable-housing-by-allowing-duplexes-in-all-neighborhoods/) on a broad bipatisan basis as well (and decried as "war on the suburbs"). Everyone wants an increase in supply, but mostly not "in their back yard".

Comment: It certainly does follow that rent-controlled property is worth less.

Answer (score 0):

#### Yes, there are. Biden fits into this category. Kinda.

[MarketWatch](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/heres-where-2020-presidential-candidates-including-elizabeth-warren-and-kamala-harris-stand-on-affordable-housing-2019-07-25) says:

> Joe Biden wants a first-time homeowner tax credit

And since a tax credit is essentially giving out money (less taxes for you  = more money for you), you get paid by the government to be a first time home owner. This makes homes cheaper, *but only if you are a first time home owner*. For everybody else, homes cost the same amount.

Comment: The question was not about _making homes cheaper_ but about _reducing housing prices_.

Comment: @user4556274 I thought those were the same thing, did I make a mistake?

Comment: The tax credit you're mentioning is counter productive.  More money actually means higher house prices, not lower prices.

Comment: "Biden fits into this category" Oof. He must be terribly disappointed by last 6 months of changes to US housing prices.